# iAd App Network will be Discontinued 30 June 2016 will be error already have iAd apps?

Tags: ios, iad

Apple says:

> iAd App Network will be Discontinued 30 June 2016

Will there be an error or a warning in the iAd apps I already have?

**What will happen to my earnings after this date?**

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a business concern, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official blogpost Apple says:

> The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. Although we are no longer accepting new apps into the network, advertising campaigns may continue to run and you can still earn advertising revenue **until June 30**. If you’d like to continue promoting your apps through iAd until then, you can create a campaign using iAd Workbench. **We will continue to keep you updated**, but if you have any questions, contact us.

That means you won't be able to promote campaigns or display iAd ads in your app starting June 30.

Apple didn't give clear information on how existing apps will be exactly handled (they will probably do so soon as the last sentence suggests), but I presume they will just **stop displaying the ads**, so you won't earn money anymore.

Comment: I published my app (providing iAd) on 2nd of March. Wondering why my app wasn't showing ads I decided to write an email to iAd support. This is what they answer: `Thank you for your inquiry. We are no longer accepting new apps into the network (effective January 15, 2016).

Your app was submitted for review on February 28, 2016. For this reason, your app is not receiving live ads.`